# Autodetect could not find javascript runtime

Tags: javascript, rubygems

I am trying to run a rails app and am using rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.5. 
I am new to rails and  need help as I think I have broken my system trying to fix this issue.

My error messages:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\Vicko>cd.. 
C:\Users>cd..  
C:\>cd sites  
C:\Sites>cd myblog    
C:\Sites\myblog>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-script-
2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-script-
2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-script-
2.4.1/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-script-
2.4.1/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-4
.0.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-4
.0.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/myblog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

C:\Sites\myblog>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although your screenshot of the error is helpful, it is pretty unreadable. It would be better if you did a copy-and-paste of the error messages into your question. Use the [edit] button to update  the text of the question. Copying text from a command prompt window is pretty easy. Just right-click call the menu, select `Mark` and drag across the text, press enter to copy and then cntrl+v to paste into this question. Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks very much Brian

Comment: @VictorAduba did you solve your issue